# How I can save radio button output in database using codegnitor rest API

Tags: rest, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using Codegnitor rest framework I want to save  radio buttons output either 1 of first or 2 for 2nd radio. Like its 2 language English and French . 1 for english radio button checked or 2 for french.

Till now I tried to write API like this

```
function update language(){
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $language = array(
            'language' => $data['language'],
        );

        $result = $this->db->insert('language', $language);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        if($result == 1){
               echo json_encode( array('success' => true ) );               
            return;
        }else{
            echo json_encode( array('success' => false ) );     
            return;
        }
    }
```

As I dont know how to retrive radio button input in rest APi. any  help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View

```
$('input[type=radio][name=language]').change(function() {

     $.ajax({
        url : "Rest Api URL",
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data : this.value,
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Controller

```
function update language(){
    $data = $this->post('language');
    $language = array(
        'language' => $data,
    );

    $result = $this->db->insert('language', $language);
    if($result == 1){
           echo json_encode( array('success' => true ) );               
        return;
    }else{
        echo json_encode( array('success' => false ) );     
        return;
    }
}
```